# How do I run code inside the Atom editor?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm Trying to run python code inside Atom.

I've run the package installed as per a previous query thread on here, and even added a new path on the environment variable section of the computer.

Run `CTRL+SHIFT+B` and still I'm getting the message `python not found...`

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Does python work on the command line?

Comment: And if you've updated env vars... A restart won't hurt.

Comment: Yep. Able to run it via command prompt no problems. Will give restart a whirl. Assume you mean computer and not just the atom editor? :D

Comment: Yeh the whole thing won't hurt

Comment: Cheers matey. Will give it a whirl and get back.

Comment: That's probably what Stuart said, env variables are not updated. It would be nice if you reinstalled the package via `apm install package-name` or using Settings View, if you haven't done that already.

Comment: Thanks Marcello. I will give that a try as well.

Comment: With pure dumb luck this seems to have worked. Frustrated with Atom, I downloaded Visual Studio - as per Stu's suggestion. VS seemed to attach a path to the env etc. And that seemed to force Atom to do what I wanted it to do. Sheer s***housery